# passphrase recovery for open pgp secret key

Tags: github, commit, openpgp, passphrase

I tried to commit changes in GitHub from visual studio code. But it asks me to enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key. I couldn't remember my passphrase. So, now I am looking for how to reset it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got my solution to my problem. I had set my passphrase as my GitHub password. I lost a whole day googling how to reset the passphrase for OpenPGP secret key.